# What exactly does need for POI Excel API

Tags: java, apache-poi, jexcelapi

I'm working on program that make Excel data via POI API 3.9 .

but there are many Jar files in directory as follows.

```
poi-3.9-20121203 
poi-excelant-3.9-20121203  
poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203 
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203 
poi-scratchpad-3.9-20121203 
ooxml-lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0  
lib/commons-logging-1.1 
..etc.
```

I just need creating, reading and writing excel files . i'm confused what jar files is need.

please tell me what files i got to import. I have read many domcuments on website . But i'can find it about that.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You probably have to import all of them. As many frameworks, Apache POI is splitted in different libraries. Apache POI also uses external libraries like XML Beans.

On the [Apache POI website](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html), you will find the list of components and for which goal there are needed, look at the [Component Map](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) section.

Typically if you are handling only old Excel files, you don't need the `poi-ooxml` dependency.

Note that your list of external dependencies is listed in the *Prerequisites* column of the second table of the Component Map section, as described there you also need additional libraries: `commons-logging`, `commons-codec`, `log4j`.

Finally, to avoid headaches with dependency management, you could use a tool like Maven which cares of this for you.

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about your dependencies too much in your case. Just use a tool like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/), and add the [POI dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/3.9):

**Maven**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle**

```
'org.apache.poi:poi:3.9'
```

This will give you the right dependencies.

Comment: I've never heard like that tool .Thank you !

Comment: You're welcome. And I'd really recommend using a tool like this, it will save you from tons of issues!

Answer (score 2):

You need just 5 jars for your mentioned tasks

for example if we are using apache 3.9

```
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
poi-3.9-20121203.jar
poi-ooxml-3.9-0121203.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-0121203.jar
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
```

Comment: dom4j definitely not needed anymore

Answer (score 1):

If you use Maven for project build, then you can simply add the following two dependencies on your project -

```
<!-- Apache POI -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
  <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
  <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

This will download all the required jars for you.

[Here](https://github.com/sayembd/excelparser) is a demo project that I've developed demonstrating the excel reading approach. The above lines are taken from my project pom. This approach works just fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to in my project

Answer (score 1):

(1)Hi, here I am posting a link where you will get all the information related to your question.

http://selenium-testng.com/test-data-through-excel/

(2)You can download all the required jars from this URL

http://poi.apache.org/download.html

(3)extract the URL and include all the jars in your classPath

(4)For MS Excel Examples you can check the following sites. It has all the examples required.

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

For standalone project you need the below jars.

commons-logging-1.1.jar

dom4j-1.6.1.jar

jsr173_1.0_api.jar

log4j-1.2.13.jar

poi-3.8-20120326.jar

poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar

poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar

resolver.jar

xbean_xpath.jar

xbean.jar

xmlbeans-qname.jar

xmlpublic.jar

Answer (score 0):

You can use ver 3.9 or ver 3.8 instead. But I find that poi ver.3.9 remove some class(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook for example) which till provides on poi-3.8-20120326.jar. So verify if those class used on your project.

Hope this help!

Comment: Apache POI 3.9 is several years old, why on earth are you suggesting to people to use such an old version?

Comment: uhmm, you are right but this not really an advice about up-to-date version. This is the warning about library changing among versions. Maybe someone till use an-several-years-old version and met this trouble like me. Hope this can help them!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the below link

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-read-write-excel-file-using.html

Worked for me :)

Working Edited Code:

```
public static boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() {
    String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
    String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
private static boolean saveExcelFile(MainActivity mainActivity, String fileName) {

        // check if available and not read only
        if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) {
            Log.w("FileUtils", "Storage not available or read only");
            return false;
        }

        boolean success = false;

        //New Workbook
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

        Cell c = null;

        //Cell style for header row
        CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
        cs.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIME.index);
        cs.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        //New Sheet
        Sheet sheet1 = null;
        sheet1 = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");

        // Generate column headings
        Row row = sheet1.createRow(0);

        c = row.createCell(0);
        c.setCellValue(DBHelper.INVENTORY_PROJECT_CODE);
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        c = row.createCell(1);
        c.setCellValue(DBHelper.INVENTORY_PROJECT_UPC_BAR_CODE);
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        c = row.createCell(2);
        c.setCellValue(DBHelper.INVENTORY_PROJECT_NAME);
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        c = row.createCell(3);
        c.setCellValue(DBHelper.INVENTORY_PROJECT_QUANTITY);
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        c = row.createCell(4);
        c.setCellValue(DBHelper.INVENTORY_PROJECT_PRICE);
        c.setCellStyle(cs);


        ArrayList<String> arrayList1 = dbHelper.getAllRecords();

        int rowno = 1;
    int columnno=0;
            for(String red : arrayList1){
                columnno = 0;
                Row row1 = sheet1.createRow(rowno);
                String[] parts = red.split(Pattern.quote(","));
                for(String str : parts){
                    c = row1.createCell(columnno);
                    c.setCellValue(str);
                    c.setCellStyle(cs);
                    columnno++;
                }
                rowno++;
            }

        sheet1.setColumnWidth(0, (15 * 500));
        sheet1.setColumnWidth(1, (15 * 500));
        sheet1.setColumnWidth(2, (15 * 500));
        sheet1.setColumnWidth(3, (15 * 500));
        sheet1.setColumnWidth(4, (15 * 500));


        // Create a path where we will place our List of objects on external storage
        File file = new File(mainActivity.getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName);
        FileOutputStream os = null;

        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            wb.write(os);
            Log.w("FileUtils", "Writing file" + file);
            success = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("FileUtils", "Error writing " + file, e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("FileUtils", "Failed to save file", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (null != os)
                    os.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }

        return success;


}
```